# Is an Android Intent equivalent to a Java Event?

Tags: java, android, events, android-intent

I'm trying to understand Android Intents and I understand the concept of a Java event and an EventListener.  Are these similar or the the same?

Comment: No there are two different things ,

Answer (score 0):

Intent in Android, is used to express an "intention" as the name implies, to perform an action over another component.  One common usage of intent is to use it along with startActivity(intentObject), where the object contains the information(contexts) of the starting and openning activity, see below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyActivityB);//pass the information(contexts of the current activity and the activity I want to open).
startActivity(intent);//Use startActivity method to start the activity defined in the object intent.
```

Other actions include: openning an app to send an email, open a social media, etc.